# Solving the RMS and Average values

Tags: power, ac

Determine the rms and average values of the following current/voltage waveforms.
[image]

But before getting the form factor, I should know the RMS value and the average value of the waveform.

My only problem is I can't solve the RMS and Average valueby its formula.

Any help will be truly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: So... you want your homework solved like this?

Comment: Please give me the solution. I am learning AC by myself.

Comment: OK. You start first....

Comment: So share your thoughts and attempts first.

Comment: Average value should not take too much head-scratching.

Comment: Perhaps this might help : http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/accircuits/ac-waveform.html

Answer (score 2):

This is the way to solve a problem like this:

1. What is the period of this signal?
2. What different blocks do you distinguish in one period?
3. Of each block, what is the RMS value?
4. Then what is the RMS value of one period?
5. Then what is the RMS value of the signal?

Comment: This is the right idea. OP should try this process and comment on which step they're stuck on.